# Using Calendar, how can i discover relative date?

Tags: java, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get date of last Friday from specified date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944760/how-to-get-date-of-last-friday-from-specified-date)

Using `java.util.Calendar` (or any other library), is there a way i can find out what the Date of what Month of what Year was "Friday 2 weeks ago"?

Please advise

Comment: Check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944760/how-to-get-date-of-last-friday-from-specified-date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Calendar vCal = Calendar.getInstance();
vCal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -2); //two weeks ago
vCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY); //friday

int vDay = vCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); //day
int vMonth = vCal.get(Calendar.MONTH); //month
int vYear = vCal.get(Calendar.YEAR); //year

Date d = vCal.getTime(); //full date
```

Good luck.