# Get nearest DateTime by specifying hour in Joda Time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I need to get Joda's `DateTime` object which will represent next (nearest) 8 AM of Moscow time. I.e. if now 7 AM of Moscow time, then I want to get 8 AM of the same day (which will happen in 1 hour), and if current time is more than 8 AM of Moscow time (for example 3 PM or 15:00), then I need to get 8 AM (8:00) of next day.

Is there some simple built-in method to do it?

For now I think I will do it using this code/pseudocode:

```
// get current moment in default time zone
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
// translate to Moscow local time
DateTime dtMoscow = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Moscow"));

if (dtMoscow.getHourOfDay >= 8) {
   dtMoscow = dtMoscow.plusDays(1)
} 

DateTime result =  dtMoscow.withHourOfDay(8).withMinuteOfHour(0).withSecondOfMinute(0)
```

Comment: This question's been asked previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749278/how-can-i-get-a-datetime-corresponding-to-next-occurence-of-hour-minute

Comment: Within the scope of Joda-Time, no simple built-in method. So your workaround is fine.

Comment: But don't forget to set the millis to zero, too.