# How to get the whole working week(Day's from Monday to Saturday), from our current date

Tags: c#, date

I need to get the current working week from our current day.
Example:

22.11.2022(Tuesday) should return me the dates
from 21.11.2022(Monday) - 26.11.2022(Saturday)

27.11.2022(Sunday) should return me the next week:
28.11.2022(Monday) - 03.12.2022(Saturday).

I found this stack overflow question, but in Java(Don't really understand, how to translate it to c#): [How to find nearest week day for an arbitrary date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321537/how-to-find-nearest-week-day-for-an-arbitrary-date)

Comment: Well, .NET's `DateTime` object has a `.DayOfWeek`, and methods such as `.AddDays`, etc. so that should be enough to get you started. Note that `DayOfTheWeek` is an enum with numeric values ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=net-6.0)). If you're a bit lost, try doing it on paper. Armed with only the knowledge that the 22nd of November 2022 is a Tuesday, what is the date of the first day of the week? What is the date of the last day of the week?

Comment: Ah, so I just googled it, and the day of the week is a constant int that means that the Java code won’t even need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
(DateTime start, DateTime end) GetWorkingWeek(DateTime fromDate)
{
    var start = fromDate.Date.AddDays(1.0 - (int)fromDate.DayOfWeek);
    var end = start.AddDays(5.0);
    return (start: start, end: end);
}
```

The `fromDate.Date` strips the time from the `DateTime`. The `DayOfWeek` is an enum made of the numbers from `0` for Sunday to `6` for Saturday, so casting the `DayOfWeek` to an `int` and subtracting that many days from `fromDate.Date` brings the date back to Sunday. The `1` adds a day to Monday. Then adding `5` gets Saturday.

Now, from your sample input:

```
DateTime[] fromDates = new[]
{ 
    new DateTime(2022, 11, 22),
    new DateTime(2022, 11, 27),
};

(DateTime start, DateTime end)[] workingWeeks =
    fromDates
        .Select(GetWorkingWeek)
        .ToArray();
```

That gives:

[image: output]

Comment: Do you mind explaining the syntax, I don't really get it.

Comment: @koogel - I've added explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an overkill. But I created a small simple self explanatory Console Program for your problem statement.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the date for finding the List of WrokWeek in mm/dd/yyyy. If you do not eneter any date. Today's date will be taken by default");
        string inputDate = Console.ReadLine();

        DateTime parsedInputDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        DateTime.TryParse(inputDate, out parsedInputDateTime);

        DateTime inputDateInDateTime = parsedInputDateTime != DateTime.MinValue ? parsedInputDateTime : DateTime.UtcNow;            

        // Now we find out the Day of the week from the input Date
        var dayOfWeekForInputDate = inputDateInDateTime.DayOfWeek;

        // Just find the Nearest Sunday (Day=0) in the past
        int nearestSundayDiff = dayOfWeekForInputDate != DayOfWeek.Sunday ? dayOfWeekForInputDate - DayOfWeek.Sunday :  0;

        // Now using the difference value we basically know how far we have to subtract to reach Sunday
        // When we reach Sunday we add one more day to get Monday and rest is knida self-explanatory
        DateTime nearestSunday = inputDateInDateTime.AddDays(-nearestSundayDiff);

        DateTime currentDay = nearestSunday.AddDays(1);

        // Just Loop through the days and print out the week dates from Monday to Saturday
        while (currentDay.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {                
            string s = currentDay.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            Console.WriteLine(currentDay.DayOfWeek.ToString() + " : " + s);
            currentDay = currentDay.AddDays(1);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This Console program takes in a string in mm/dd/yyyy format and parses it in the backend. If the format is incorrect or no date is entered it just takes the current UTC Date and Time.

Then we basically try to find the nearest Sunday as it's integral value is 0 in C#. Then we just loop through to the Saturday and print out the result. I would not suggest considering this code production worthy as I wrote it in 5 mins and can certainly think of atleast 3-4 things I can do to prevent errors etc. Feel free to comment out the mistakes.

This is the response when I entered 12/02/2022

[image: Input-Date-12/02/2022]

Hopefully this answers your query. Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

For me this works pretty well. It gives a list of the working days of the week

```
public List<DateTime> GetWorkingDaysOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    List<DateTime> workingDays = new List<DateTime>();
    date = date.AddDays(-(date.Date.DayOfWeek.GetHashCode() - 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        workingDays.Add(date.AddDays(i));
    }
    return workingDays;
}
```

Comment: This works great, I'm still testing out all the answers, I modified your code a bit, so it wouldn't count the sunday in. Also made an extension method for it.