# How to find next dates of some specific day occured after specific date using java?

Tags: java

```
String specificDate=2013+"-"+06+"-"+20;
String day="Monday";
```

How to find the next date where Monday comes that is after that `specificDate`?

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem.

You can use java.util.Calendar and then increment it until you get to the next Monday.

Answer (score 3):

You either want to look at [Java's Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), given you're looking at rules over dates, I'd recommend Joda.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();  
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
 now.setTime(sdf.parse(dateString));
 int weekday = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);  
 if (weekday != Calendar.MONDAY)  
 {  

     int days = (Calendar.SATURDAY - weekday + 2) % 7;  
     now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);  
 }  
 Date monday = now.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really use a higher level Date library to do that for you. Unfortunately, java's built in Date and Calendar class are far less than ideal. You can take a look at this library, which has come the de facto standard for date manipulation among Java developers, until the new JDK design is finalized.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Calendar class for that.

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();  
c1.set(2013, Calendar.JUNE, 20);

int weekday = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);  
if (weekday != Calendar.MONDAY) {
    // calculate how much to add
    // the 2 is the difference between Saturday and Monday
    int days = (Calendar.SATURDAY - weekday + 2) % 7;
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 5, 20);
    int diff = Calendar.MONDAY - c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (diff < 0) {
        diff = 7 + diff;
    }
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, diff);
    Date monday = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this with the standard API is setting the day of week to Monday and then advancing one week:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY); // Sets c to this week's Monday
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);                      // Advances c to next week's Monday
```

Note that if the first day of the week in your culture is Sunday and the date your start with is a Sunday, the `set` method moves the date to the following Monday-not the preceding one-and you end up calculating second Monday after the given date. If the first day of the week is Monday everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For Java 8, you could use something like...

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2013, Month.JUNE, 20);
LocalDate nextWed2 = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
```

or...

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2013, Month.JUNE, 20);
LocalDate nextWed2 = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
```

if the select date was `MONDAY`, but you wanted the next `MONDAY`

As demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242809/find-next-occurrence-of-a-day-of-week-in-jsr-310) in much more detail

Or if you prefer to use JodaTime...

```
    LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2013, DateTimeConstants.JUNE, 20);
    LocalDate nextMonday = new LocalDate(date);
    if (date.getDayOfWeek() >= DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY) {
        nextMonday = date.plusWeeks(1);
    }
    nextMonday = nextMonday.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY);
```

Which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636038/joda-time-how-to-get-the-next-friday)