# Find next occurrence of a day-of-week in JSR-310

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

Given a JSR-310 object, such as `LocalDate`, how can I find the date of next Wednesday (or any other day-of-week?

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate nextWed = ???
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer depends on your definition of "next Wednesday" ;-)

JSR-310 provides two options using the [TemporalAdjusters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

The first option is [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#next-java.time.DayOfWeek-):

```
LocalDate input = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate nextWed = input.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY));
```

The second option is [nextOrSame()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-):

```
LocalDate input = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate nextWed = input.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY));
```

The two differ depending on what day-of-week the input date is.

If the input date is 2014-01-22 (a Wednesday) then:

- `next()` will return 2014-01-29, one week later
- `nextOrSame()` will return 2014-01-22, the same as the input

If the input date is 2014-01-20 (a Monday) then:

- `next()` will return 2014-01-22
- `nextOrSame()` will return 2014-01-22

ie. `next()` always returns a later date, whereas `nextOrSame()` will return the input date if it matches.

Note that both options look much better with static imports:

```
LocalDate nextWed1 = input.with(next(WEDNESDAY));
LocalDate nextWed2 = input.with(nextOrSame(WEDNESDAY));
```

`TemporalAdjusters` also includes matching `previous()` and `previousOrSame()` methods.