# Getting next Monday using JodaTime

Tags: jodatime

I am using `JodaTime` to figure out what the current `LocalDate` is and then getting the following Monday's date.

When I use the following method and the current day is a Monday, instead of getting the following Monday, it gets the current day.

```
private LocalDate getNextMonday() {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    date = date.plusWeeks(1);
    return date.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
}
```

**Why is my method not working in getting the following Monday when it is currently a Monday?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Joda-Time does not offer a built-in elegant solution so you have to do your own workaround like this:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
int old = today.getDayOfWeek();
int monday = 1;

if (monday <= old) {
    monday += 7;
}
LocalDate next = today.plusDays(monday - old);
System.out.println("Next monday: " + next);
```

If you are only interested in setting to next monday the code can be simplified as follows:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
int old = today.getDayOfWeek();
LocalDate next = today.plusDays(8 - old);
```

About your question -

> Why is my method not working in getting the following Monday when it
>   is currently a Monday?

the answer is that the method `withDayofWeek()` **sets the date to Monday in CURRENT week** (which is dependent on the week model (ISO used in Joda-Time, but US-week differ in when a week starts for example - not supported by Joda-Time).

Note that with [JSR-310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242809/find-next-occurrence-of-a-day-of-week-in-jsr-310) (not applicable to Android) or my library Time4J there is a more modern approach - see this [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/)-code:

```
PlainDate nextMonday =
    SystemClock.inLocalView().today().with(
        PlainDate.DAY_OF_WEEK.setToNext(Weekday.MONDAY)
    );
System.out.println("Next monday: " + nextMonday);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
int targetDay = 1; //or DateTimeConstants.MONDAY
int nowDay = now.getDayOfWeek();

if (nowDay >= targetDay) return now.plusWeeks(1);
else return now.withDayOfWeek(targetDay);

//Or using ternary operator:
return (nowDay >= targetDay ? now.plusWeeks(1) : now).withDayOfWeek(targetDay)
```