# Getting specific date of the next month with time API

Tags: java, java-time, localdate, date

I need to find the date of the second Sunday of the next month using java.time API. I am new to time API. I tried this code:

```
LocalDate current=LocalDate.now();
```

This is giving me current date but `LocalDate` does not have any such method where I can get nextMonth or something like that. Please suggest. I need to use time API only.

Comment: Sooo, with a little bit of [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636038/time-how-to-get-the-next-friday), I came up with `LocalDateTime.now().withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)).with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));` which comes up with `2018-08-12T13:34:15.734`, but there might be a simpler way

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using a `TemporalAdjuster` like this:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println("First day of next month: " + now.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth()));
System.out.println("First Friday in month: " + now.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)));

// Custom temporal adjusters.
TemporalAdjuster secondSundayOfNextMonth = temporal -> {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(temporal).plusMonths(1);
    date = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(2, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
    return temporal.with(date);
};
System.out.println("Second sunday of next month: " + now.with(secondSundayOfNextMonth));
```

Comment: A little more general (and therefore a little more complicated) than what was asked for, but fine. I think Sunday was asked for, and you’re giving Saturday, but the asker can probably fix that.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks! Changed my example to use Sunday instead of Saturday

Comment: When writing a `TemoralAdjuster` for dates, it is best to use `TemporalAdjusters.ofDateAdjuster()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#ofDateAdjuster-java.util.function.UnaryOperator- . For reference, I also recommend using static imports for the methods on `TemporalAdjusters` and `DayOfWeek` as I feel the result is clearer to read,

Answer (score 2):

[alexander.egger’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550408/5772882) is correct and shows us the building blocks we need (+1). For the question as stated the only `TemporalAdjuster` we need is the one we get from the library. The following may feel a bit simpler:

```
    LocalDate current = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Easter"));
    LocalDate secondSundayOfNextMonth = current.plusMonths(1)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(2, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
    System.out.println("2nd Sunday of next month is " + secondSundayOfNextMonth);
```

Output running today was:

> 2nd Sunday of next month is 2018-08-12

Since the month doesn’t begin at the same time in different time zones, I have preferred to give explicit time zone to `LocalDate.now`.

[“Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible, But Not Simpler”](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/) (I think I read it from Bjarne Stroustrup, but he probably stole it somewhere else).